# Copy one AD attribute field to another field

Tags: powershell

I had a project where I had to copy the `DisplayName` attribute to the `extensionAttribute1` attribute.

Normally , I able to copy `DisplayName` attribute to the `extensionAttribute1` attribute.

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(DisplayName=*)' -Properties Description, DisplayName |            
 Select-Object * -First 5 |            
 ForEach-Object {Set-ADObject -Identity $_.DistinguishedName ` 
  -Replace @{extensionAttribute1=$($_.DisplayName)}}
```

But, I need to parse text between brackets like below. After I will copy it to the extensionAttribute1 attribute.

```
  DisplayName attribute :  John Conner (IT DEPARMANT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the `-Split` operator.

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(DisplayName=*)' -Properties Description, DisplayName | 
   Select-Object * -First 5 | ForEach-Object {
      Set-ADObject -Identity $_.DistinguishedName -Replace @{extensionAttribute1=$(($_.DisplayName -Split "\((.*?)\)")[1])}
   }
```

The `-Split` operator in this case is using a regex match. It will typically yield a three-index array. The first element `[0]` will be the characters before the parentheses. The second element `[1]` will be the characters within the first set of parentheses. The last element `[2]` will be the remaining characters of the string value, which in this case will be a blank line. This solution will still work if you have multiple sets of parentheses but ONLY want to capture the string within the first set.

- `\(` is a literal match of `(`.
- `(.*?)`

  - `.*?` is an ungreedy match of any characters
  - `()` tells `-Split` to keep everything within parentheses. Typically it will remove your matched string.
- `\)` is a literal match of `)`

See [About Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-6) for more details.

Comment: I just copied your code as is. I can fix the formatting

Comment: @Arbelac, I fixed the formatting. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with a predefined Regex object to keep the code easy to read:

```
# create a regex to get the part of the DisplayName between the brackets
$re = [regex] '\((.+)\)'

Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(DisplayName=*)' -Properties Description, DisplayName |            
    Select-Object * -First 5 |   
    ForEach-Object {
        $name = $re.Match($_.DisplayName).Groups[1].Value
        $_ | Set-ADObject -Replace @{extensionAttribute1=$name}
    }
```

Regex Details:

> ```
> \(         Match the character “(” literally
> (          Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
>    .       Match any single character that is not a line break character
>       +    Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> )
> \)         Match the character “)” literally
> ```

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer But I have simple issue. I am running script but I am getting ` -Replace : The term '-Replace' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function

Comment: @Arbelac That is why I chose a different form, so there is no need to use the backtick as line continuation symbol. Lots of mistakes happen with that because it is either overlooked, or , as it looks like in your code, **it is followed by a space character.** Both result in errors.